# Разделить переменную при превышении лимита символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, telegram-bot

Для своих нужд пишу telegram-бота. У **api** есть ограничение на размер одного сообщения - 4096 символов.

Вот так получаю переменную с результатами поиска по файлу:

```
with open('filename.list', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if searchstring.lower() in line.lower():
                result= str(result) + str(line) + '\n'
```

Пример результата:

> String1 param1 param2\n String2 param1 param2\n

и т.д.

Далее этот результат отправляется сообщением:

```
if result:
    bot.send_message(chat_id="SomeID", text= str(result) )
```

Как мне разделить сообщение с результатом на несколько сообщений, в случае превышения лимита? При этом, сделав это построчно, чтобы у меня не переносились результаты по полстроки.

Comment: в лоб она вот так делается - https://eval.in/934891

Comment: в сторону: не используйте `.readlines()` здесь. Файл в Питоне уже итератор по строкам является. Не используйте `str()` на строках (и вообще избегайте явного вызова) -- это бесполезно. Если не сложно, то можете упомянуть, где вы увидели `for line in f.readlines()` конструкцию (вместо `for line in file`)? Что вы хотите достичь, вызывая `str()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так можно:

```
s = 'string1\nstring2\nstring3\n' * 10000  
while s:  
    if len(s) > 4096:  
        tmp = s[:s.rfind('\n',0,4096)+1]  
        s = s[s.rfind('\n',0,4096)+1:]  
        bot.send_message(chat_id="SomeID", text=tmp )  
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id="SomeID", text=s )  
        break
```

Comment: если длина одной линии будет больше 4096, код работать не будет. s.rfind + 1 незачем вычиллять два раза

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы послать избранные строки из файла кусками, не превышая предел по количеству символов [примерно]:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    chunk = file.readlines(limit)
    while chunk:
        found_lines = [line for line in chunk if searchstring in line.casefold()]
        if found_lines:
            send(''.join(found_lines))
        chunk = file.readlines(limit)
```

Можно руками размер считать, чтобы свои условия для предела определить, к примеру в байтах в выбранной кодировке считать:

```
chunksize = 0
chunk = []
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        if searchstring in line.casefold():
            chunksize += len(line.encode())
            if chunksize > limit: # send chunk
                send(''.join(chunk))
                del chunk[:]
                chunksize = len(line.encode())

            chunk.append(line)

if chunk: # send the rest
    send(''.join(chunk))
```

Answer (score 0):

более короткий вариант ответа `Iriskin`

```
s = 'string1\nstring2\nstring3\n' * 10

def maxll(s, lmax=90):
    if s:
        m = s.rfind('\n', 0, lmax) + 1
        tmp = s[:m]
        print(len(tmp), tmp)  # bot.send_message(chat_id="SomeID", text=tmp)
        return maxll(s[m:])
```

если длина одной линии будет больше lmax, работать не будет